# Pandas join or merge 2 data frames 1 having 1 record and other having multiple records

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have 2 data frames

```
df1 = 
 city.population  city.sys.population  cnt  cod  message  tmp
               0                    0   38  200   0.1642    1
```

df2=

```
  A                    B   C   D       E       tmp
  0                    0   38  200   0.1642    1
  0                    0   38  200   0.1642    1
  0                    0   38  200   0.1642    1
  0                    0   38  200   0.1642    1
```

I want to merge/join the two data frames on tmp and should get the result like

```
A                    B   C   D       E       tmp       population cnt cod
0                    0   38  200   0.1642    1         0          38  200
0                    0   38  200   0.1642    1         0          38  200
0                    0   38  200   0.1642    1         0          38  200
0                    0   38  200   0.1642    1         0          38  200
```

But I'm getting values for `population`, `cnt` and `cod` only for the first record. Is there any way to have the values in first record filled for all rows for `population` `cnt` and `cod` fields

Comment: show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can join two data frame with append. Did you try it?

```
df1.append(df2)
df1.head()
```

Let me know if works.

For more look at the documentation
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/merging.html

Answer (score 0):

`df3 = pd.merge(df2, df1, on='tmp', how='outer')` should give you what you want. This is equivalent to a full outer join in SQL, if you are familiar with that terminology.

What this does is smush the two data frames df1 and df2 together so that the `df3.tmp`  column is equal to the union of the values in df1.tmp and df2.tmp (i.e. the list of values you would get if you did `df1.tmp + df2.tmp`. So any rows in df2 that have `df2.tmp == 1` will get the info from df1 where `df1.tmp == 1` This will work if you want to include all the data from both df1 and df2. This way, if you have a column in df1 with a value in 'tmp' that is NOT in df2, your new dataframe will have 'NaN' values for columns A,B,C,D,E, and the data from df1, but you don't lose any data in the merge.

eg if df1 =

```
pop  syspop    ct    cod     msg  tmp
0    0.0     0.0  30.0  200.0  0.1642  1.0
1  0.0     0.0   0.0    0.0  0.0000  3.0`
```

then df3=

```
    a    b     c      d       e  tmp  pop  syspop    ct    cod       msg
0  0.0  0.0  38.0  200.0  0.1642  1.0  0.0     0.0  30.0  200.0  0.1642
1  0.0  0.0  38.0  200.0  0.1642  1.0  0.0     0.0  30.0  200.0  0.1642
2  0.0  0.0  38.0  200.0  0.1642  1.0  0.0     0.0  30.0  200.0  0.1642
3  0.0  0.0  38.0  200.0  0.1642  1.0  0.0     0.0  30.0  200.0  0.1642
4  0.0  0.0   0.0    0.0  0.0000  2.0  NaN     NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN
```

If you want other combinations of df1 and df2 (for example, you don't care about any values that are in df1 that are not also in df2), you would change the 'how' argument. see the pandas docs here for more info: 
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra